# for loop stops when if statement is satisfied

Tags: if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to count how  many times the unique words in a LinkedList appear using this code:

```
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < a.size(); i2++)
        {
            word2 = a.get(i2);
            for(int j2 = 0; j2 < a.size(); j2++)
            {
                if(word2 == a.get(j2))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(word2 + " : " + counter);
            counter = 0;
        }
```

But the counter prints out:
Alphabet : 1
Alright : 1
Apple : 1
Alphabet : 1
Alright : 1
Apple : 1
Alphabet : 1
Alright : 1
Apple : 1

There is obviously more than one of the words, but the counter never gets higher then one. I think that the inner for loop is stopping when the if statement is satisfied, but I don't want it to. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you use debugger to walk through the code? Then give us more info?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
    word2.equals(a.get(j2))
```

Using "==" you compare the references to those String which are not equal.

And by the way you will print the counter multiple times for the same word if you have repetitions. Let's say you have the word Apple on 2 positions in your list. When you will reach these 2 positions the counter will go up to 2 and you will print (Apple: 2) 2 times

Comment: So how do I make it print only once>

Comment: You can copy those elements into a Set and run the same code. Or you can create a new List and while you are going through your initial list you verify if the element is in your new list. If it is, it means you already counted it so you can skip it. If it isn't compute the counter and then insert the element in your new List. 
Or if you don't need your List to remain as in the initial state you can add between the brackets in the "if"
        a.remove(j2)

Comment: I tried removing like you suggested, but it messes up the count on the last words. Like it'll say that "alright" is there twice, but it's there three times. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like java to me. You can't compare string with (==) operator.

```
 if(word2.equals(a.get(j2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a new addition!!!

As suggested by @user3412998 its better to use Sets so that you can avoid duplication.

Now if you need to use ArrayList only then  you need to take one element and check if there are multiple copies of that element using loop.The condition can be checked by .equals method if you are using string or my contains method incase you are inserting objects(dont forget to override your equals  method in the corresponding class). This is a very tedious process and I do not recommend it.

I believe that the easiest way will to not to add duplicate elements in your array list. to accomplish that look at the code below..

```
if(!a.contains(word)){
   a.add(word);
}
```

Note word is a String object.

Here I am checking weather the string is already contained in the ArrayList, before insertion.
make a bit of modifications so that you can use it, for arrays, or for directly inputting data etc..

I hope this helps..